# How do you combine the sandhi rules for consecutive 3rd tones and half 3rd tones in a sentence like 我很高兴?

Tags: pronunciation, sandhi

In a sentence like:

> 我很高兴 (wǒ hěn gāo​xìng)

two 3rd tones are in a row. So according to 3rd tone sandhi, it must be pronounced

> wó hěn gāo​xìng

On the other hand, a 3rd tone (hěn) is followed by a non 3rd tone, so it must be pronounced [half 3rd tone](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/pronunciation/Four_tones#Updated_Tone_Diagram).
By putting these two rules together we get:

> wó hěn(half-3rd) gāo​xìng

Is this method of combing two tone rules correct?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this appears to be the same question as [your previous question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/45610).

Comment: The answer is "yes", but it feels a bit silly to leave an actual answer with only one word. :)

Comment: @Becky李蓓♦ Please read the most upvoted answer in the previous question. You will see why confusion on the part of OP is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

我很高兴 (wǒ hěn gāo​xìng) in Mandarin Chinese is pronounced in the following tones:

2nd-(half)3rd-1st-4th

It's exactly as you wrote. Well done!

About tone sandhi, you can find a very simple explanation in Chinese at the following link:

https://m.sohu.com/a/360277551_747777/?pvid=000115_3w_a